# Problem with Taylor&Francis latex file

Tags: bibliographies

I am preparing a submission to Applied Economics and I downloaded the latex package from the website of the editor ([here](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=raec20&page=instructions)).

Regarding bibliography, it uses a specific style (tdcaf.bst), available in the package, to produce a Chicago-style bibliography.

I tried to compile the file (interactcadsample.tex) using the bib file interactcadsample.bib and putting the lines below where the bibliography is supposed to appear:

```
\bibliographystyle{tfcad}
\bibliography{interactcadsample}
```

Unfortunately, it seems not to work and I cannot undestand why.

THE MWE is:

```
\documentclass[]{interact}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\title{My title\thanks{My acknowledgements.}}

\author{
\name{First author\textsuperscript{a}\thanks{CONTACT First author. Email: firstauthor@email.com} and second author\textsuperscript{b} and third author\textsuperscript{a}}
\affil{\textsuperscript{a}Department X, University Y; \textsuperscript{b}Department K, University Z}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent The abstract

\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Keywords
\end{keywords}


\section{Introduction}

In the introduction I want to cite \citep{Alb05,Gre08,Sch87} and \citealp{Mor08}.

\bibliographystyle{tfcad}
\bibliography{interactcadsample}

\end{document}
```

As you may notice, when compiling the file citations and bibliography are missing. Any help on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX?

Comment: @egreg. Egg on my face!!! you are right….sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments just running bibtex

Comment: Agreed. Is this something I can do by myself?